# Google BigData ETh Query Question

Tags: contract-debugging

This is a question for all those that are familiar with crafting Google BigData queries to extract data.

My request is fairly simple. I'm looking to extract a definitive list of smart contracts with unique bytecode.

The first query I sent through only gave me the # of contracts with unique bytecode (believe the # is about 25k or so).

Then I changed my query to the following:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT `bigquery-public-data.ethereum_blockchain.contracts`.bytecode AS unique_bytecode,
  FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.ethereum_blockchain.contracts`
```

All this does is return the **bytecode** for all results that match the query...which is close to what I'm looking for but still no cigar. **Instead**, I'm looking for the accompanying smart contract addresses for the results that match the query (*hope this makes sense how I've worded it*).

In laymen's terms, I'm trying to craft a Google BigData query that returns the addresses of all smart contracts with unique bytecode (i.e., no smart contract address that's returned should have a bytecode that matches any other returned result from the query).

Comment: don't know bigquery, but in any other SQL database I would try a grouped query, something like `SELECT MIN(address), bytecode FROM contracts GROUP BY bytecode`

Comment: @user253751 Thanks for that tip. Do I still need the `DISTINCT` before the bytecode modifier to stipulate that the results should be unique? If you happen to know a SQL query that will achieve this same goal, that works too bc Google BigData has a feature that allows you to convert SQL queries to BigData format.

Comment: I literally just told you an SQL query that would achieve the goal

Comment: @user253751 you're right. I forgot to double back to this. Put in the SQL command & it gave me exactly what I was looking for. I sprinkled in the `AS` phrases for the sake of labeling the columns on output, but that was just for aesthetic / visual purposes. You nailed it man. Thanks! Wish I could give you best answer but it won't let me do it for comments.

Comment: now it's an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Bigquery's language but in SQL you can do this:

```
SELECT MIN(address), bytecode FROM contracts GROUP BY bytecode
```

This puts all contracts with the same bytecode into a group and from each group it selects the bytecode and the lowest address.

Comment: Thanks! This solved it for me. Want to note for anyone that may come across this question in the future that the query above is valid as written as a BigData query.

Additionally, I made some minor additions to the code for the sake of having it label columns for the output as well as specifying the data source: `SELECT MIN(address) AS address, , bigquery-public-data.ethereum_blockchain.contracts.bytecode AS bytecode FROM bigquery-public-data.ethereum_blockchain.contracts GROUP BY bytecode`